# add colors to paint-app in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, paint

i have a little problem with eclipse/android.
i am trying to mak my own paint-app in android. my problem is i can only paint with one color(black) , now i want to add 3 more colors(red,green,blue). 
im still a newbie to android developing, and i dont know how i can add that option.
anyone has any suggestions?

here is my code so far

-SingleTouchEventView

```
package nl.hr.teken0;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
  }






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

SingleTouchActivity

```
package nl.hr.teken0;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What this class is exactly SingleTouchEventView(this, null)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a color picker. An example: https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Just import it like other libraries so that the source is in the "src" folder and then add the layout to the preferences file.

Preferences xml file:

```
<yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
        android:key="your_preference_key"
        android:defaultValue="0xff6699cc" 
        android:title="Pick a color" />
```